# Run a python Module from sl4a

Tags: android, python

I have installed py4a and sl4a, then I copied the existent python module, pybluez, into my phone to storage/sdcard0/Download.
I imported the module with the option Import Modules from py4a  and installed it.
How can I execute the module?

Tanks,
Reea

Answer (score 0):

Execute? You don't execute modules, normally a module has an entry point for example

```
import module
module.main()
```